# Image = Null error when trying to send image over java UDP socket connection with client and server

Tags: java, image, sockets, udp, transfer

So I am trying to write code to implement an image being sent over in bytes packet by packet within Java over client and server. 
[This is the jist of the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdBgw.png)

Here is the code for the server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class UDPServer {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
   DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);                                               //makes the datagram socket at the port 9876 for dat transfer 
   byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];                                                                  //allocate memory for data being recieved
   byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];                                                                     //allocate memory for data being sent
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

   DatagramPacket receiveByte = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
   serverSocket.receive(receiveByte);
   byte[] data = receiveByte.getData();
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
   BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(bais);
   ImageIO.write(image2, "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\Demon FFA\\Documents\\Network Design\\Phase 2\\word1.bmp"));
   System.out.println("Image receieved!");
```

Here is the code for client side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class UDPClient {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));            //create input stream for client to server message
         DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();                                          //create the socket for the client
         InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");                                  //change the hostname into an ip address with DNS
         byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];                                                            //allocate memory for data being sent
         byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];                                                         //allocate memory for the data being recieved


      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Demon FFA\\Documents\\Network Design\\Phase 2\\word.bmp"));
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos);
      //baos.flush();
      byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int i;
      int c = 0;

      for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        buffer[c] = data[i];
        c++;
        if (i%1024==0){
        c = 0;
        }
        DatagramPacket sendByte  = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, IPAddress, 9876);
        clientSocket.send(sendByte);
    } 
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

[CMD Error: Image= Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9bJ4.png)

Comment: The error you have attached is coming out of the server. Take a look at: byte[] data = receiveByte.getData(); What is in the data array after this call? Have you run this code in debug? Take a look at this answer for how to use a debugger https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385174/1978785

Comment: Your server needs to know how many bytes should be read before the image is fully loaded

Comment: Your client is capable of sending more then one packet, but you server is only expecting one.  How would the server know when it's received the last packet?

Comment: I'm kind of new to java, so I am not sure how I would implement it to expect more than one packet. I have been looking around for an implementation similar to this that does have a server taking more than one packet, but no luck. I am extremely lost.